# Is it possible for a Gmail gadget to create a custom filter on a user's email?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I was thinking of developing an app that would apply some machine learning algorithms on a user's email and then create a custom filter or highlight certain emails based on some parameters. Is this possible via a contextual gadget or a Google apps script. I get the impression that it is possible to access an email's contents only **after** the user opens it and not before.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about when a gmail gadget operates with scan. It is per email not on the list.

You could use GAS directly on the user's inbox however it would need to be polling in the background and to avoid running into quota limits you'd have to weave some clever magic or accept a non-real-time solution.

You could combine gmail gadgets and GAS but in practice I have found App Engine a better fit for that hybrid solution.